# How long can a char be?

Tags: c

Why does `int a = 'adf';` compile and run in C?

Comment: Your compiler *should* give you a warning about a multi-character character constant. But why wouldn't it compile?

Comment: Note that it should produce a nice warning if you compile with -Wall, which you should do. All in all, we're all another brick in the -Wall, anyway.

Comment: I used VC6.0 to compile, which did't give warning

Comment: @ytyisme: You realize that VC6.0 is [from 1998](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_C%2B%2B#32-bit_versions), don't you? And there might be an option to increase warnings, even with that old version.

Comment: @ytyisme: Try `/Wall`, which is documented for current versions, at least. I don't know if it goes back that far, but it's worth a try.

Answer (score 8):

The literal `'adf'` is a **multi-byte character constant**. Its value is platform dependent. Don't use it.

For example, one some platform a 32-bit unsigned integer could take the value `0x00616466`, and on another it could be `0x66646100`, and on yet another it could be `0x84860081`...

Comment: @Joe: As with all platform-dependent constructions, you *can* of course use them, but you must be aware of the fact that the behaviour is determined by more than just your C code. A good programmer would be careful do document such code very visibly.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that anyone should do it! Only that it has been done before (i.e. works if you know what you're doing, under some circumstances).

Answer (score 2):

This, as Kerrek said, is a multi-byte character constant. It works because each character takes up 8 bits. 'adf' is 3 characters, which is 24 bits. An `int` is usually large enough to contain this.

But all of the above is platform dependent, and could be different from architecture to architecture. This kind of thing is still used in ancient Apple code, can't quite remember where, although file creator codes ring a bell.

Note the difference in syntax between `"` and `'`.

`char *x = "this is a string. The value assigned to x is a pointer to the string in memory"`

`char y = '!' // the value assigned to y is the numerical character value of the character '!'`

`char z = 'asd' // the value of z is the numerical value of the 'string' data, which can in theory be expressed as an int if it's short enough`

Comment: No, it's not right. It may compile, but you will get warnings. This trick was used a *long* time ago by some programmers to deal with constraints of the day. Do not use this in new code.

Comment: It's not give a warning. And "printf(&a);" also can run in VC,which give a warning

Comment: Okay. GCC would give you a warning. If VC doesn't want to warn you, you can take the warning from all the comments on this page!

Comment: Also, only pass a correct null-terminated string to `printf`. The above code will certainly give you unpredictable behaviour (from printing 'adf' to printing half of memeory, to a segmentation fault)

Answer (score 0):

It works just because "adf" is 3 ASCII characters and thus 3 bytes long and your platform is a 24 bit or larger system. It would fail on a 16bit system for instance.

Its also worth remembering that although sizeof(char) will always return 1, dependending on platform and compiler more than 1 byte of memory space could be assigned to a char hence for

```
struct st 
{
int a;
char c;
};
```

when you:

`sizeof(st)` a number of 32 bit systems will return `8`. This is because the system will pad out the single byte for `char c` to 4 bytes.

Comment: "ASCII" is not immediately relevant to the topic. It's just some random encoding; why bring it up?

Comment: Your reasoning about the struct is misleading. The compiler does *not* assign more than one byte of memory to a `char`. Rather, the struct is *padded* so as to meet its alignment requirements. (There are platforms on which a `char` is 32-bits wide, but that just means that *bytes* are 32-bits wide on that platform. The char still only takes one byte.)

Comment: Furthermore isn't "adf" a string litteral and therefore 4bytes in length because of the terminating null character?

Answer (score -1):

ASCII. Every character has a numerical value. Halfway through this tutorial is a description if you need more information http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Variables

Edit_***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*____**

```
char letter2 = 97; /* in ASCII, 97 = 'a' */
```

This is considered by some to be extremely bad practice, if we are using it to store a character, not a small number, in that if someone reads your code, most readers are forced to look up what character corresponds with the number 97 in the encoding scheme. In the end, letter1 and letter2 store both the same thing – the letter "a", but the first method is clearer, easier to debug, and much more straightforward.

One important thing to mention is that characters for numerals are represented differently from their corresponding number, i.e. '1' is not equal to 1.

Comment: The point is there's more than one character in the character literal, which is unusual. I don't see that in your tutorial.

Comment: Touche. I remember seeing the answer to your problem a long time ago in a c++ book, there is a rule for these things. Unfortunately I don't remember it.

Comment: What has any of this to do with "ASCII"? ASCII is a character encoding, and the OP asks about literal constants in C.

Comment: @KerrekSB characters all have values, that what it has to do with ASCII. Click on the link in my answer...

Comment: @Gabe: I know that, but ASCII is just one of many encodings. What's relevant to the discussion is perhaps the "platform's execution character set"...

Comment: I know that! I just want to know why a char can like this